# How to stop scroll during the click event in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used more effects.The effects likes based on the drag the scroll in browser or going to down of the page in my home page.

I have implemented the top button, it can goes top of the page. When i click the top button. It's go to top, but very slow ie, step by step moves to top, because of the existing effects.

Top button coding:

```
jQuery('#to-top').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 800);
});
```

How to stop all other effects(scroll based effects) and allow the #top-top button scroll only?

Make sure once moved to top, the scroll based effects will work..

Comment: You should add more information.

Comment: `jQuery('html,body').stop().animate({scrollTop: 0}, 800);` or more brutally `jQuery('html,body').stop(true,true).animate({scrollTop: 0}, 800);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `stop()` to your function call

```
jQuery('#to-top').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('html,body').stop()animate({scrollTop: 0}, 800);
});
```

then to continue the scroll effect you will have to recall it, I'm not sure how do you habdle this

Answer (score 0):

You just have to stop current animations using `JQuery` `stop()` method (read more [here](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)) so your code should look like:

```
jQuery('#to-top').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   jQuery('html,body').stop().animate({scrollTop: 0}, 800);
});
```

Comment: what do you mean with "not working" does it show any error?